# Restricting an MDS code to a subset of coordinates

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

If we have an $(n,k)$ [MDS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound#MDS_codes) and we take a subset of coordinates in a set  say $J$, where $|J| > k$.  If $c$ is a codeword in the original MDS code let $c_J$ denote its projection on the set $J$. Is it true that set of codewords $\{c_J \}$ is also an MDS code? Is there an easy reference for this? Is there a similar results for maximum rank distance (aka MRD) codes by Gabidulin?